# What is affecting my character in sunlight?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I'm playing Skyrim PS3. I have skipped around on quests. I just finished the Dawnguard questline, and defeated Seranas Father. I chose to do another side mission and completed it. I then decided to start a side quest that I received before I installed Dawnguard. When I came out of the cave into the sunlight the screen blurred and tuned red. Because of my sucky TV  I am unable to read the top left of the screen where it tells me what is wrong. My stats have dropped and active affects gives me two things related to vampirism. I am a werewolf and have changed to beast form, drank cure disease potions and visited shrines. I even tried talking to innkeepers to get the quest to be cured...nothing is working. It's been longer than the three days but I'm not being attacked nor has my appearance changed. Is this a glitch from doing a quest I received before installing Dawnguard?

Comment: vampire-ism?  ? ?

Comment: I thought so, but I didn't think I could be infected if I was werewolf. I'm not even sure how I was infected. But there seem to be no visible changes to my character, just stats have dropped. No one has told me I look sick nor have I been attacked..I think I may have screwed myself somehow and will have to start a new game :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really is a glitch, something like this happened to me when I purchased [skyrim-dawnguard](/questions/tagged/skyrim-dawnguard) as well.

I had way too many open quests and many of them just got glitch'd as soon as I started getting more and more quests from the dlc. NPC's wouldn't respond to the delivery of what they asked, caves emptied, etc.

It started getting weirder when I defeated a vampire camp, and, being a werewolf acquired that eternal vampire-ism.

Since it was too much of an annoyance to me to have my questlog all messed up, plus the eternal dicease, I've decided to abandon my beloved Rufus and start a new game *(it hurt, but it's always fun to start over)*

Comment: Thanks :) I figured it was a glitch. I'd hate to start over, but it seems like my only options at this point